# Why can't I push local Docker image to Docker Hub repo?

Tags: docker, push, dockerhub

I have Docker ID, let's say -> KN, and created a private repo. I can log into Docker Hub via CLI too. I run a container based on a image & commit that container to an image with following command

```
docker commit ub18 reponame/ub18 ==> successfull
```

but when I push that image like following, it doesn't upload.

Output of Docker images shows this image on top.

```
docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
standard/ub18       latest              c8ebc0f1dd75        12 seconds ago      102MB


docker push reponame/ub18  ==> gives error
The push refers to repository [docker.io/standard/ub18]
7660ded5319c: Preparing 
94e5c4ea5da6: Preparing 
5d74a98c48bc: Preparing 
604cbde1a4c8: Preparing 
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Comment: add the error information

Comment: You need to login fist with "docker login"

Comment: @Akshaybarahate  ok I updated Qs

Comment: @Mihai I think I mentioned that I can successfully login

Comment: is `reponame` your dockerhub id?

Comment: @michalk no, docker ID is lets say KN

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So to push your images to your Docker Hub repo first you have to login to Docker Hub repo using username and password:

```
docker login
```

Then perform tagging of your image properly :

```
docker tag image_id yourhubusername/reponame:tag
```

Your image tag has to be in this specific format.
Then to push :

```
docker push yourhubusername/reponame:tag
```

assuming you are logged in.

If you want to gain more information about it, refer to [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/repos/).

Comment: Note that you have to log in with `docker login` even if you want to push to a _public_ repo. This is not mentioned in the docs as far as I can tell.

Comment: If the login does not work, run the following commands: `sudo service docker stop && rm ~/.docker/config.json && sudo service docker start` then run `docker login` again.